# Legacy Fortran Code Compiling Problems

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

I have legacy Fortran code ranging in date from the 60s to 90s that I need to be able to compile.

The code works as it is written, even if it uses some old practices that are no longer standard.
It was successfully built on the Intel Visual Fortran 2011 Compiler and Visual Studio 2008. I am now on Visual Studio 2012 and Intel Visual Fortran 2013. I can't seem to find the right options to flip to allow it to build.

The major problem is that huge equivalence arrays are used and often instead of passing an array or an actual pointer to a subroutine they are just passing a single value of the pointer equivalence arrays and somehow it is implied to use a sequence of values. The main errors are

- the type of actual argument differs from the type of dummy argument
- if the actual argument is scalar, the dummy argument shall be scalar unless the actual argument is of type character or is an element of an array that is not assumed shape, pointer, or polymorphic

Once again. I know that the code does work as built. Any helpful suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I know of an aerospace installation that is dealing with this problem by converting the Fortran to C.  The Fortran is proving difficult to maintain without compatible compiler support from Microsoft.

Comment: I mean I know I could rewrite the code...

Comment: Or fix the errors, so that the new compiler is happy.  Or use the older compiler.

Comment: Fortran compiler vendors know that backward compatibility is important to their customers. I suggest asking your question on the Intel Visual Fortran Compiler for Windows forum and mentioning what compiler options used to work with your code. They may be able to provide you with compiler options that work with IVF 2013. If not, they may even treat your problem as a bug and fix the compiler.

Comment: Did you contact your technical support? Intel Visual Fortran is a commercial product with a support coming with the license. Contact the Premier support or the support forums https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows

Comment: Yes I am aware of those things... The problem is that is a 2 month (minimum) fix whereas compiling the old stuff as is, is a 2 minute fix.

Comment: Those errors is your code are detected by compile time warning and checking options.  If you turn those options off, those errors generally won't (and can't) be detected.  Depending on the specific thing that the compiler is identifying, the phrase "no longer standard" in you question probably should be written "were *never* standard".

Comment: @IanH yeah I agree I was being politically correct. I just don't know what other options there are other than what I tried. I tried turning off all of the "/check: ****"'s but to no avail.

Comment: See response on the intel forum (which is the best place for this sort of stuff).  /check:xxx controls runtime diagnostics, /warn:noxxx is what you play with to suppress compile time diagnostics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my particular problem was to go to project properties -> diagnostics -> Language Usage Warnings -> Check Routine Interfaces and set it to "No".

Answer (score 0):

It is about 1 year since your query, but I just had a similar problem that involved fortran pointers and dynamic memory allocations that I was able to fix.

A key problem was that memory address location values in the legacy code were equivalent to INTEGER*4 datatype whereas in the new operating system they were INTEGER*8.  The way dynamic memory allocation worked was that the location of a dummy array 'HEAP(ii)' was used as an anchor point, relative to which the absolute address given by "malloc" could be referenced.  If HEAP base address (i.e. LOC(HEAP(1)) was 11111, and if the absolute address freed by "malloc" was at memory address 1731111111111111, and if HEAP had been assigned to be integer*4 (or equivalently real*4), then the first location freed by "malloc" was equivalent to HEAP(  (1731111111111111-11111)/4 + 1).  Using HEAP(iaddress) as an argument in subroutine calls with iaddress at these insanely large index values allowed the appropriate portions of HEAP to be used as the array argument in the called subroutine.

Places with problems included:

POINT1.) The value of the absolute address of freed memory, as given by "malloc", had been stored at a position in HEAP() just after the stored calculation-data values.  This address value was stored there so that it could be used later to free memory.  If this INTEGER*8 address was stored across the boundaries of INTEGER*8 address registers for the new operating system/compiler, it would give a "HEXADECIMALS of DOOM" style crash, when you tried to access this stored INTEGER*8 memory address value based on the index of INTEGER*4 HEAP.  This could be avoided by including an extra padding of 1 INTEGER*4 location before the storage spot for this stored value of the memory address.  This was needed whenever the number of stored data values in the preceding data segment was an odd number of XXXX*4 data values.  The stored memory address value could be read as an INTEGER*8 address, when it was needed, by EQUIVALENCE-ing INTEGER*4 HEAP() to INTEGER*8 LONGHEAP() and using an index value in longheap() that was about 1/2 of the insanely long index value used as the array index in HEAP() (with -1's and +1's to account for fortran indexing of arrays that starts from 1)

POINT2.)  All variables that stored memory address locations needed to be tracked down and switched from INTEGER*4 to INTEGER*8.  This was tricky in subroutines that called functions that called functions ...  One construct to look for is the swapping of memory locations, TEMP = Iaddress; Iaddress = Jaddress; Jaddress = TEMP:  in such swaps, make sure TEMP is INTEGER*8.  Other memory-address arithmetic and temporary storage variables can cause problems as well.  Also once you have made this switch, you need check whether these new INTEGER*8 variables have been used as arguments in calls to subroutines and functions. If so, you need to modify the called functions/subroutines appropriately and make sure that datatypes are consistent in all of the other calls to the same function/subroutine.

It might have been possible just to switch everything to *8 and check for statements involving the indexing arithmetic, but I wasn't sure if the new arrays of logical*8 values and some of the fancy stuff with the old integer*2 arrays would have worked.

Comment: You should have been able to change the default kind value for integers, and that may have helped you.